# I'm unable to send GET variables along with domain address to Facebook using FacebookRedirectLoginHelper

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm upgrading my system from facebook **sdk3.2** to **sdk4**.

Previously, we could pass GET parameters like:

```
// page where user will press login button (sdk3)
Facebook::getFBInstance($facebook);
$loginParams = array(
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.mywebsite.com/requesthandler.php?destiny='.urlencode('http://www.mywebsite.com/some_other_page.php'),
    'scope'        => FACEBOOK_PERMISSION_SCOPE
);
?>
<a href="<?=$facebook->getLoginUrl($loginParams);?>">Login </a>
```

But in SDK 4, **The first code for helper returns an error but the second one works**. I've followed all the steps on facebook developers page.

```
// page where user will press login button (sdk4)

use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( FACEBOOK_API_ID, FACEBOOK_API_SECRET );
// this code returns error
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://www.mywebsite.com/
            requesthandler.php?destiny='.urlencode('http://www.mywebsite.com/some_other_page.php') )
// wheareas this one works
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://www.mywebsite.com/
            requesthandler.php' )
?>
<a href="<?=$helper->getLoginUrl(explode(',', FACEBOOK_PERMISSION_SCOPE));?>"> Login </a>
```

Here,

destiny - the **page** from where user clicked the login button, so that i can redirect him to that page once the login process is completed.

requesthandler.php - page that does everything for facebook login.

```
//requesthandler.php

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( FACEBOOK_API_ID, FACEBOOK_API_SECRET );
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URI_SAME_AS_THE_ONE_IN_REQUEST_PAGE );
try{
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
}
catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ){
    echo $ex->getResponse();
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}

$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me');
$response = $request->execute();
$userprofile = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::classname());
print_r($userprofile->getName());
exit;
```

the error returned is:

```
 Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Facebook\FacebookRequest::__construct() must be an instance of Facebook\FacebookSession, null given, called in /var/www/local/requesthandler.php on line 52 and defined in /var/www/local/classes/apis/facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php on line 182
```

### How can i pass GET variables ?